# How to remove -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER:FILEPATH -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER:FILEPATH from Visual Studio Code CMake extension

Tags: c++, linux, visual-studio-code, cmake, build

I am trying to use `ccache` from CMake extension in Visual Studio Code. For this I added the following to `settings.json`:

```
"cmake.configureArgs": [
    "-DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_LAUNCHER=ccache",
    "-DCMAKE_CUDA_COMPILER_LAUNCHER=ccache",
    ...
],
```

However, the problem is that Visual Studio Code CMake extension adds the following flags to the command-line, and they seem to override `ccache` flags I passed:

```
-DCMAKE_C_COMPILER:FILEPATH=/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc-9 -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER:FILEPATH=/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-g++-9
```

Is there a way to get rid of the latter flags?

Comment: Variables `CMAKE_C_COMPILER` and `CMAKE_C_COMPILER_LAUNCHER` are independent variables and shouldn't affect one on another.

Comment: Thanks, @Tsyvarev . This hint gave me the idea that I should use `-DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_LAUNCHER=/usr/local/bin/ccache` from within VS Code, and now `ccache` works. Would you like to post this as an answer?